# SP 2013 : Specific item in a lookup field cannot be filtered

Tags: lookup-column, filter

the list A has a lookup field connected to list B in field Title. One of the items in list B has title "CCAA".

On A/ViewAllitems, i can filter in column lookup:listB:Title for every item, except for the "CCAA" = it returns 0 items. I can see that there are items that has lookup value="CCAA". In an A item with lookup field "CCAA", I can select the lookup field and it shows the B/Showites/title="CCAA". So the lookup is working fine, but doesn't filter!

Also, when you press the filter icon, (and shows all the values), this value is the last one, even if there are items with "DA", "FA". On the other hand, in B/Viewallitems, the items are in correct alphabetical order.

I have edit an item in list A, delete/insert the same lookup listB/"CCAA" with the same characteristics.

Any thoughts?

[image: the offended item is the last one. Alphabetically, it shouldn't be here]

Comment: Is this CCAA value shown in the filter dropdown that you can invoke from table column heading? Can you post a partial screenshot?

Comment: Can you retrieve this item via Server side Object model, JS object model or ASMX Web Services and verify that the XML representation contains these exact characters and not similar characters from another codepage?